# Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. unresolved supertypes: LifecycleActivity

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, dependencies, build.gradle

I can't compile my android project.

## Gradle Log Error

Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath:
class com.test.projectName.ui.user.login.LoginActivity, unresolved supertypes: LifecycleActivity
class com.test.projectName.ui.PxActivity, unresolved supertypes: LifecycleActivity
class com.test.projectName.ui.PxFragment, unresolved supertypes: LifecycleFragment
class com.test.projectName.ui.symbol.add.SearchSymbolsAdapter, unresolved supertypes: Adapter
Adding -Xextended-compiler-checks argument might provide additional information.

## Project build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.3.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-processor:1.0.0-beta10'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

## App build.gradle

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher
import java.util.regex.Pattern

plugins {
    id('com.android.application')
    id('kotlin-android')
    id('com.google.gms.google-services')
    id('kotlin-android-extensions')
}

task aaaprintVar {
    doLast {
        println System.getenv('HOME')
        println System.getenv('ANDROID_KEY_ALIAS')
        println project.property("BUILD_NUMBER_TAG")
    }
}

/* AutoVersion Helpers */
def autoVersion_props = new Properties()
def folder = new File("$project.rootDir/scripts")
if (!folder.exists()) {
    // Create all folders up-to and including B
    folder.mkdirs()
}
new File(folder, "autoVersion.properties").withWriterAppend { w ->
    w << ""
}

def autoPropsFile = new File(folder, "autoVersion.properties")
autoPropsFile.withInputStream { autoVersion_props.load(it) }

def readVersionCode = { ->
    def versionCodeString = autoVersion_props.getProperty("gitCommitCount") ?: "0"
    return Integer.parseInt(versionCodeString)
}
/* End AutoVersion Helpers */

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    buildToolsVersion '30.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 33
        buildConfigField "String", "GIT_COMMIT_HASH", "\"" + gitCommitHash() + "\"";
        println "VersionCode: " + readVersionCode()
        versionCode readVersionCode()
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["room.schemaLocation":
                                     "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }
        testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    }
    preBuild.doFirst {
        println "PreBuild"
        println "Running auto-version.sh"
        println runAutoVersion()
        project.task("printProps")
    }

    task autoVersion {
        doLast {
            println "PreBuild"
            println "Running auto-version.sh"
            println runAutoVersion()
            println "Finished running auto-version.sh"
            project.task("printProps")
        }
    }


    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile releaseKeyStoreFile
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
        qa {
            storeFile releaseKeyStoreFile
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
        release {
            storeFile releaseKeyStoreFile
            storePassword code_sign_props.getProperty("ANDROID_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD") ?: 'android'
            keyAlias code_sign_props.getProperty("ANDROID_KEY_ALIAS") ?: 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword code_sign_props.getProperty("ANDROID_KEY_PASSWORD") ?: 'android'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            debuggable true

        }
        qa {
            minifyEnabled false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.qa
            debuggable true

        }
        release {
            buildConfigField "Boolean", "RELEASE_TYPE", "true"
            buildConfigField "Boolean", "ENABLE_DEVICE_ID_CHANGE", "false"

            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled false
            //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }

    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
dependencies {
    def butterknife_version = "10.2.1"
    def retrofit_version = "2.9.0"
    def okhttp_version = "4.10.0"
    def dagger_version = "2.38.1"
    def hockeyapp_android_sdk_version = "4.1.4"
    def socket_library_version = "2.3"

    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation "com.jakewharton:butterknife:$butterknife_version"
    annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:$butterknife_version"
    implementation "net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.9"
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.5.1'
    annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    annotationProcessor 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.0'
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$okhttp_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$okhttp_version"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$dagger_version"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger_version"
    implementation project(':shinobicontrols-android-charts-premium-java-1.9.3-1')
    implementation "net.hockeyapp.android:HockeySDK:$hockeyapp_android_sdk_version"
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.0.1'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:16.0.0"
    implementation "com.neovisionaries:nv-websocket-client:$socket_library_version"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.6"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'

    /* Tests */
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation "com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2:mockito-kotlin:2.0.0-RC1"
    testImplementation 'androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.0.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
}
}
```

Tried changing lifecycle version but I don't know what version to put.